# Check if a POST value is empty

Tags: php

I want to check if the post if filled or not (post variable empty or not) 
I'm using "isset", and it just does not seem to work, everytime i submit the form it says filled even when the form is not filled.

PHP code :

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
          echo "filled";
      } else {
          echo "not filled";
      }
?>
```

HTML code :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

when i printed $_POST, it says :

[username] => 
[submit] => Submit

Comment: So check `username` then.

Comment: @u_mulder yes it works, but i want to do it with isset, this is a simple case, am having a huge form, and i want to check if(isset($_POST["submit"]))

Comment: `$_POST["submit"]` is a button, it is always set as you __press this button__ to submit.

Comment: it just does not make anysense i've seen lots of tutos using the same function? even using just $_POST will always give me that its filled

Comment: So this tutos check that someone is trying to __submit__ the form, they not check that form is empty or not filled.

Comment: @u_mulder yes i see, i guess i have to check one by one then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `!empty()` instead of `isset();`

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"])) {
        echo "filled";
    } else {
        echo "not filled";
    }
```